# GlassFish v2 - How to externalize deployment descriptor sun-ejb-jar.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

When deploying my application I need to separate my configurations. This way any configuration changes does not require a new build.

My application has

app.ear

- |---- app-ejb.jar
- ```
       |---- sun-ejb-jar.xml
  ```

I need to remove sun-ejb-jar.xml out of app-ejb.jar and also app.ear, so when I make configuration changes in sun-ejb-jar.xml, I do not need to build and deploy, but only restart the application.

Is this possible with Glassfish v2 ?